# How to read from cassandra in google-dataflow

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a use-case I want to read everything from a Cassandra table and create a PCollection. Is there a library I can use for that or should I just use Cassandra driver and code from the scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing Cassandra source for Dataflow that I'm aware of (though there is a [sink](https://github.com/benjumanji/cassandra-dataflow/)). Please consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007771/google-cloud-dataflow-user-defined-mysql-source) about reading from MySQL - the considerations for connecting to Cassandra would be very similar. [BEAM-244](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-244) is also related.